# How to create new connection when throw error using Entity Framework 6 and npgsql?

Tags: entity-framework-6, connection, npgsql

I am a C# developer using Entity Framework 6, npgsql, and unity DI.
As title, I ran into PostgresException when create log, and I need to close current connection and recreate a new connection in EF and npgsql.

here is code

```
public interface IPgRepo
{ 
    IDbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    int SaveChanges();
    void Dispose();
}


public class PgRepo : DbContext, IPgRepo
{
    public PgRepo(string connString) : base(connString)
    {
    }

    IDbSet<Log> IPgRepo.Logs { get ; set ; }

    int IPgRepo.SaveChanges()
    {
        return SaveChanges();
    }

    void IPgRepo.Dispose()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}

public class LogCommand
{
    private IPgRepo _repository;
    public LogCommand(IPgRepo repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void AddLog(Log log)
    {
        try
        {
            _repository.Logs.Add(log);
            _repository.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (PostgresException ex)
        {
            //todo: how to create new connection ??
            _repository.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/connection-management

Comment: @apincik It look like I cannot use DI like unity container. I need to manage its connection.